# Stop the Git For Windows Stopped Working messages for Visual Studio 2017 RC

Tags: windows, git, visual-studio

I'm doing code review for an app with Visual Studio 2017 RC. Whenever I click on a file I get a stream of `Git for Windows Stopped Working` error messages.

I tried disabling git in the project by going to `tools > options > Source Control > Plugin Selection` and choosing `None`, but the error messages continue.

Anyway to stop them? I don't need git to work, I just want to look at the code and run it.

Comment: *"I tried disabling git in the project by going to [...]"* - That's not the per-project setting you are looking at. I don't know where per-project SCM settings are stored in Visual Studio 2017. Fixing your Git installation may be a viable option, too.

Comment: Git and Github Desktop are installed and working. Not sure how to further fix it.

Comment: Are you clicking on files in Solution Explorer?

Does it do this for all repositories (for instance, if you create a simple new repository, do you still these errors?) or just for this particular one?

Comment: I haven't tested creating new repositories. I just need it to work with this one.